# JavaScript error in Magento admin panel

Tags: javascript

In my admin section of magento I am getting error
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

How I resolve it please let me know

Comment: Can you please provide more details. Your question title and description has no relevancy. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: jquery library added in head?

Comment: Have you installed any 3rd party modules recently?

Comment: jQuery isn't included by default in Magento1, so you need to check 3rd party module or theme requirements

Comment: How I can include jquery for magento backend

Answer (score 1):

- It depends on which version of Magento you're using. From ver. 1.9 onward, magento comes with jQuery, but before 1.9, it doesn't have jQuery.
- So, you're getting this error, because in your theme (admin/frontend)
  jQuery functions are called, but you don't have jQuery installed in
  your server.

**Solution:**

- http://www.activo.com/how-to-load-jquery-and-prototype-in-magento-admin-panel/
- http://www.magesolution.com/blog/how-to-add-jquery-in-magento/